# Using gmail smtp server for emails in asp.net web site in IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-6, smtp, gmail

I've uploaded my asp.net web site to IIS 6.0, and it's currently working, except for sending e-mails.  In my asp.net test server, I was able to use gmail as an smtp server for outgoing e-mails from my gmail account.

In the IIS live server version, when I click the button control that is supposed to send the message, the loading bar of the browser only reaches 25% and then stops, no error or message.

The following is my code for the button click event that sends the e-mail.

```
    private void sendUsername() 
    {
    /**
     * Sends user's username to 
     * their listed e-mail address.
     * 
     */
    string username = Session["retrievedUsername"].ToString();

    string usernameSent = "usernameSent";

    string from = "mandizi84@gmail.com";

    string to = enterEmailTextBoxTwo.Text;

    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

    mail.To.Add(to);
    mail.From = new MailAddress(from, "The All-Star R.E.C. Center", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    mail.Subject = "ASRC password retrieval.";
    mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    string htmlBody = "Hi " + username + "," + "<br /><br />";
    htmlBody += "Your username is " + "'" + username + "'" + "." + "<br /><br />";
    htmlBody += "If you don't remember your password, return to the Credential Recovery section to get a new password." + "<br /><br />";
    htmlBody += "Your membership is much appreciated." + "<br /><br />";
    htmlBody += "Thank you," + "<br /><br/>";
    htmlBody += "The All-Star R.E.C. Center";

    mail.Body = htmlBody;

    mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, "password");

    client.Port = 587;
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    client.EnableSsl = true;

    try
    {
        client.Send(mail);

        Session["usernameSent"] = usernameSent;

        Response.Redirect("~/Email Confirmation.aspx", false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Exception ex2 = ex;
        while (ex2 != null)
        {
            errorLabel.Text = "Mail could not be sent. ";
            errorLabel.Text += ex2.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I did some research and read in a few places that configuring the mail server role is not necessary if I use gmail account, but in other places I did.

So my question is in IIS, do I need to configure the mail server role and then add the gmail smtp to use that smtp service in my live website on IIS 6.0?

Thanks

Update: I just removed the while loop from my catch block and received the following error:

Mail could not be sent. System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 74.125.95.109:587 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6, Int32 timeout) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at Credential_Recovery.sendUsername() in e:\Senior Design\Second Version\ASRC\Credential Recovery.aspx.cs:line 619

line 619 in my code is "client.Send(mail)"

Comment: did you checkt your firewall?

Comment: why don't you just debug this before posting as a question?

Comment: @user492238, what should my firewall settings be?  Where should I check them at, since the IIS is on a win 2k3 server? In the control panel?

Comment: @Eranga the thing is it works fine in the asp.net test server so there's no need to debug it, but in IIS the compilation tag web config's debug mode has to be set to false

Comment: yea it works fine when when everything works out(but there are other execution paths). In a web app you should log the exceptions. otherwise you will have a hard time why something went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Dont you think the While loop in your Catch block is going into an infinite loop, thus not showing you the actual error?if therez an Exception, ex2 will never be null. its like a `while(1)` statement!!

Comment: Umm...good catch, what's funny is it works just fine on test server in Visual Studio, I've never gotten an error and always receive the emails when I check my account, but in the IIS 6.0 it just loads a bit and then pauses.  I'll try to modify and see if it makes a difference in the live server version.

Comment: yea, probably the error message after you remove the while loop might help you. btw, if i were you, id print out the StackTrace: errorLabel.Text = ex.StackTrace;

Comment: I did some researching and seen to test the port 587 type the following into cmd:

"Telnet smtp.gmail.com 587"

I received the response:

"Connecting to smtp.gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host on port 587: Connect failed"

 Somehow I guess I need to open the connection.